# Join 2 tables with same PRIMARY key that is autoincrementing too

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables with both of them having the first column as PRIMARY which is also an auto incrementing. First table has 67 entries starting from 1 to 67 and the second table has 48 entries. Both of them have same columns. I want to take the content from Table2 and insert them into  Table1 such that the next entry in Table1 starts from 68. Finally I will have 115 entries in Table1 and the PRIMARY column will also show that. I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO `Table1` SELECT * FROM `Table2`
```

But it said

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Name the columns you want to insert and leave the auto_incrment columns from the insert

```
INSERT INTO `Table1` (col2, col3, col4)
select col2, col3, col4 from `table2`
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the columns you wish to enter, without the identity column.

Something like

```
INSERT INTO `Table1` (column1, column2,...,columnn) 
SELECT column1, column2,...,columnn FROM `Table2`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT database_name.schema_name.table ON 

--Do Insert Here

SET IDENTITY_INSERT database_name.schema_name.table OFF
```

Make sure there is no duplicate id thought.

[See this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms188059.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

try out this...

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (col2, col3,...)
select col2, col3,... from Table2
```

you can do it with n number of columns...
Here you need to specify column name on that you wish to insert data other than identity column(Auto Increment Column).